# How can i find out if i am part of a mining pool is it possible by entering ip into any commands in console,

Tags: mining-pools

[image]In my wallet.dat i have various encrypted data suggesting that i am some part of a pool would there be any way of finding out ,via ip/node/commands.

Comment: Did you do explicitly do anything to join a mining pool? Do you own mining hardware? Just simply having a wallet.dat and a running copy of bitcoin-core does not set you up to mine bitcoin (or join a mining pool).

Answer (score 1):

> **In my wallet.dat i have various encrypted data suggesting that i am some part of a pool**

So far as I know, the only data in a wallet.dat that is encrypted by the wallet is the private keys. This data has nothing to do with any mining pool membership.

> **would there be any way of finding out ,via ip/node/commands.**

I don't think a Bitcoin core wallet.dat would explicitly contain any information about pools or pool-membership and nor would it help you to claim unpaid money from a pool. I am not familiar with mining pools but my understanding is that they make payouts in the normal way at the time of mining (or perhaps as soon as your total of accumulated shares exceeds some payment threshold). I wouldn't expect a mining pool to hold money long term (years), though that is possible.

However there won't be any data in a Bitcoin core wallet that explicitly tells you you have some money in a custodial account elsewhere.

Comment: Essentially OP's question is similar to "here is a photo of my credit card, how do I figure out who owes me money?". The two are completely unrelated.